# Issue while adding Blockchain service in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

I am trying to add Blockchain service (Starter Developer Plan) to my Bluemix account (megjain9@in.ibm.com). While I select to create an instance, I am getting an error as shown in below screen shot.
Could you please check and advise the needful?

[Blockchain Service Error on Bluemix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVwkY.png)

Thanks,
Megha

Answer (score 0):

The Blockchain service is currently experiencing an outage, due to a network failure.

Service status is listed on the https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/support/#status, check this page for updates on a resolution.